# Understanding Deruyts construction of Weyl modules

Tags: representation-theory

I have been curious about the representation theory of the general linear group, so I did a brief web search and found [a paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/03c2/ed0ec039709799f79659e7c378c29f9d9757.pdf) that gives an explicit construction of the irreducible representations of $GL_n(\Bbb C)$ (attributed to [J. Deruyts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacques_Deruyts)) but I am not able to understand it.

To summarize: the claim is that there exists one irreducible representation for each Young diagram $\lambda$ with at most $n$ rows. The representation $V_\lambda$ is a subspace of $\Bbb C[Z]$ (polynomials over the entries of an $n \times n$ matrix $Z$, on which $GL_n(\Bbb C)$ acts). For each semistandard tableau $T$ with shape $\lambda$, an element of $V_\lambda$ is given by $e_T = \prod_c e_c$ as $c$ ranges over the columns of $T$. For each $c = (c_1, \ldots, c_\ell)$, the element $e_c$ is equal to the minor formed from rows $1, \ldots, \ell$ and columns $c_1, \ldots, c_\ell$ of the matrix $Z$. The subspace $V_\lambda$ is the span of all $e_T$ (in fact, it is claimed that the $e_T$'s form a basis).

Unfortunately, this seems to yield incorrect results; for example, fix $n = 2$ and let $\lambda$ have a single row with two boxes. There are three corresponding semistandard tableaux, namely 11, 12, 22. Each column in any case has length 1 so the corresponding minor's value is just a single entry of $Z$ from the first row. For example, if we denote the argument matrix by

\begin{equation}
Z = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

then the corresponding $e_T$'s are $a^2$, $ab$, and $b^2$, so $V_\lambda$ is supposed to be spanned by these three monomials. However, this doesn't seem to be a valid representation; the action of various elements of $GL_n(\Bbb C)$ will yield terms that involve $c$ and $d$, so this subspace doesn't seem to be closed under that action.

I am sure that I have misunderstood something but I have not been able to spot the mistake. I also looked at Fulton & Harris, but they simply state the same construction on page 237.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The action of $GL_n$ is by multiplication on the right of $Z$ (see Eq. (6) p. 27 in the linked article by Mulmuley). So the $a$'s and $b$'s do not mix with the $c$'s and $d$'s.
Moreover, the three monomials span the space of quadratic forms in $a,b$, namely, the second symmetric power of the fundamental two-dimensional representation, which is the module for the partition $\lambda=(2)$. So it's all good.

BTW, this construction was known before Deruyts and is in fact due to Alfred Clebsch. See the references in the article ["Invariant theory, tensors and group characters"](https://www.jstor.org/stable/91389) by D. E. Littelwood, or directly [here](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN250442582_0017?tify=%7B%22view%22:%22info%22,%22pages%22:%5B167%5D%7D).

Comment: Thank you. I actually knew that the multiplication is on the right, but I foolishly thought "can't that also yield an arbitrary set of 4 linearly independent linear combinations of the original 4 entries?" Whoops. GL_n is not GL_{n^2}.